# How to draw the current location information in osmdroid

Tags: java, android, android-studio, osmdroid

#### Assumption and what I want to achieve

I'm working on an application that receives current location information from an external RTK-GPS via serial communication, and draws dots or lines on an osmdroid map.

I have already realized receiving the location information and converting the received data to a type that can be displayed on TextView.

For serial communication, I am using FTDI's "usb-serial-for-android" library, and for map functions, I am using "osmdroid".

Currently

1. Receive location data from RTK-GPS via serial communication.
2. Get the latitude and longitude in double type from the received data (String type).
3. Create a GeoPoint from the acquired latitude and longitude, set it to a marker, and draw it on the map. At this time, the GeoPoint is also stored in the GeoPoint list.
   The following procedure is used to display the marker of the current location on the map. Currently, the received latitude and longitude are set to the marker and all the markers are drawn.

Eventually, I'd like to draw the trajectory of movement as a line while updating the current location marker.

#### Problems and error messages

The problem we are experiencing is that when we start drawing, the application immediately becomes sluggish and freezes.

Since 10 data are sent from GPS per second, if we try to draw all the received data on the map, the number of markers will be huge and the app will freeze.

Therefore, we tried to draw markers in 10 marker skips, but even so, the application became sluggish and froze as soon as it started drawing.

Next, when the number of data exceeded 100, I deleted the oldest data first, and the application did not freeze after starting drawing. However, I don't think it is possible to draw all the loci with this method. If possible, I would like to draw all the loci that have been moved.

My questions are as follows.

1. Is it possible to draw the movement locus using the above method and policy?
2. Is it impossible to draw such a moving locus in Android?
3. Does OSMDROID have a function to draw the movement locus?
4. Are there any similar questions?

Please let me know.

Here is my code.

```
public class MapGeneratorMainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final double MAP_ZOOM = 15.0;
    private static final double MAP_ZOOM2 = 17.0;

    static MapView mapGeneratorMainMap = null;

    public static List<Marker> currentMarkers = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<GeoPoint> currentPoints = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<GeoPoint> currentPoints2hz = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Polyline> currentTrajectory = new ArrayList<>();
    public static int receiveCount = 0;
    public static GeoPoint currentP2hz;

    public MapGeneratorMainActivity() {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        org.osmdroid.config.Configuration.getInstance().load(getApplicationContext(),
                PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()));

        setContentView(R.layout.map_generator_main_activity);
        MapView mapGeneratorMainMap = findViewById(R.id.MapGaneratorMainMap);

        mapGeneratorMainMap.setMultiTouchControls(true);
        IMapController mapController = mapGeneratorMainMap.getController();
        mapController.setZoom(MAP_ZOOM);
        GeoPoint centerPoint = new GeoPoint(aveLat, aveLon);
        mapController.setCenter(centerPoint);

        mapGeneratorMainMap.setTilesScaledToDpi(true);

        final MapTileProviderBasic tileProvider = new MapTileProviderBasic(getApplicationContext());

        ITileSource tileSource = new XYTileSource("GSI", 14, 24, 256, ".jpg", new String[]{TILE_SEVER});

        tileProvider.setTileSource(tileSource);
        final TilesOverlay tilesOverlay = new TilesOverlay(tileProvider, this.getApplicationContext());
        tilesOverlay.setLoadingBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        mapGeneratorMainMap.getOverlays().add(tilesOverlay);
        mapGeneratorMainMap.invalidate();

        FloatingActionButton myLocationButton = findViewById(R.id.myLocationButton);
        myLocationButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intentService = new Intent(getApplication(), gpsService.class); //位置情報受信サービス
                intentService.putExtra("REQUEST_CODE", 1);
                startForegroundService(intentService);
            }
        });

        //Receiver
        UpdateReceiver receiver = new UpdateReceiver();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("DO_ACTION");
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    }

    protected class UpdateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            String currentLat = null;
            String currentLon = null;

            MapView mapGeneratorMainMap = findViewById(R.id.MapGaneratorMainMap);
            mapGeneratorMainMap.setMultiTouchControls(true);
            IMapController mapController = mapGeneratorMainMap.getController();
            mapController.setZoom(MAP_ZOOM2);

            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            String msg = extras.getString("message"); //String型の位置情報
            TextView currentLocatonTextView = findViewById(R.id.CurrentLocation);
            currentLocatonTextView.setText(msg);
            String[] currentLocaton = msg.split(",", -1);
            currentLat = currentLocaton[0];
            currentLon = currentLocaton[1];
            double Lat = Double.parseDouble(currentLat);
            double Lon = Double.parseDouble(currentLon);
            GeoPoint currentP = new GeoPoint(Lat, Lon);
            if(receiveCount == 0){
                currentP2hz = new GeoPoint(Lat, Lon);
                currentPoints.add(currentP);
                currentPoints2hz.add(currentP2hz);
                currentPtMarker = new Marker(mapGeneratorMainMap);
                Drawable currentMarkerIcon = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.current_point_marker, null);
                currentPtMarker.setIcon(currentMarkerIcon);
                currentPtMarker.setAnchor(Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER, Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER);
                currentPtMarker.setPosition(currentP);
                currentMarkers.add(currentPtMarker);
                mapGeneratorMainMap.getOverlayManager().add(currentPtMarker);
                mapGeneratorMainMap.invalidate();
            }
            else if(receiveCount == 100) {
                currentPoints.add(currentP);
                currentP2hz = new GeoPoint(Lat, Lon);
                currentPoints2hz.add(currentP2hz);
                receiveCount = 0;
                currentPtMarker = new Marker(mapGeneratorMainMap);
                Drawable currentMarkerIcon = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.current_point_marker, null);
                currentPtMarker.setIcon(currentMarkerIcon);
                currentPtMarker.setAnchor(Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER, Marker.ANCHOR_CENTER);
                currentPtMarker.setPosition(currentP);
                currentMarkers.add(currentPtMarker);
                mapGeneratorMainMap.getOverlayManager().add(currentPtMarker);
                mapGeneratorMainMap.invalidate();

            }
            if(currentMarkers.size() >= 100){
                currentMarkers.get(0).remove(mapGeneratorMainMap);
                currentMarkers.remove(0);
            }
            receiveCount += 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: To indicate the position you only need one marker. If the location updates then update the position of that marker. Dont create a new marker.

Comment: To indicate the track you could draw a polyline.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments.
Would it be better to use osmdroid's MyLocationOverlay to update the current location marker? Does it work fine with external GPS?

Comment: Sorry, i have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Good morning everyone.
I was able to solve this problem.
The reason why it didn't work was that some of the data received by serial communication was not good.
After eliminating this bad data and receiving only the good data, I was able to do what I wanted.
thanks so much.